# DIV isn't show up upon DOM element removing, does the function knows about the DOM element removal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-confirm

I have the following piece of code:

```
<ul class="ul" id="selected_conditions">
  <li class="condition" data-field="asset_locations_name" data-condition="in">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete_condition" aria-hidden="true" title="Click to remove this condition from the list"></i> WHERE asset_locations_name IN(
    <span class="condition_item" data-id="1213381233">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete" title="Click to remove this item from the list" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1213381233
    </span>,
    <span class="condition_item" data-id="1212371897">
    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle delete" title="Click to remove this item from the list" aria-hidden="true"></i> 1212371897
    </span> )
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="empty_msg" style="display: none">
  There is no conditions
</div>
```

Once I click on the little icon `.delete_condition` I should remove the `li` element and if it's the last one at `#selected_conditions` then remove the `display: none` from the `#empty_msg` DIV. This is how I am doing it:

```
$(function() {
  $('#selected_conditions').on('click', '.delete_condition', function() {
    var condition = $(this).closest('.condition');
    var conditions = $('#selected_conditions li');

    $.confirm({
      title: 'Confirm!',
      icon: 'fa fa-warning',
      closeIcon: true,
      closeIconClass: 'fa fa-close',
      content: 'This will remove the whole condition! Are you sure?',
      buttons: {
        confirm: function() {
          condition.remove();

          if (conditions.length == 0) {
            $('#empty_msg').removeAttr('style');
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

It removes the `li` but doesn't show up the `#empty_msg` since `conditions.length` still `=1`. I have debug the code in Chrome Console and that's the result and I don't know why.

Why? Doesn't know the function or the DOM that the element has been removed?  How I can fix this behavior?

Maybe is me doing something wrong and if that's the case I couldn't find where I am messing up things.

I am using [jQuery Confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) for the dialogs.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/8184ok2e/10/) to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'have to query items after removing it but you're doing it before removing the item and as a result it's counting length before it was removed.

```
var conditions = $('#selected_conditions li');
```

You can just update your condition to this to get expected result.

```
if ( $('#selected_conditions li').length == 0) {
  $('#empty_msg').removeAttr('style');
}
```

Here is the working updated fiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8184ok2e/11/